# generate inline keyboard telegram bot from the database

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

hi I have some product cat in my database I want to generate inline keyboard from the theme but I want to like this

we have

```
cat1-ca2-ca3-ca4-ca5
```

I want to like this

```
cat1  cat2
cat3  cat4
   cat5
```

I need the loop for this result thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you get the values that you want to show in the keyboard, you need to store these in array. This example was did in Javascript, you must found the equivalent in php code.

If you only have 5 products you don't need a loop, just:

```
...
{
  'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
    keyboard: 
    [
      [{'text': 'cat1'},{'text': 'cat2'}],
      [{'text': 'cat3'},{'text': 'cat4'}],
      [{'text': 'cat5'}]
    ],
    one_time_keyboard: true,
    resize_keyboard: true
  })
}
...
```

If you have undefined products elements you must use a for loop:

```
var keyboard = [];
var products = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'];

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  keyboard.push([{'text': products[i]}]);
}

...
{ 
  'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
    inline_keyboard: keyboard
  })
}
```