# use for loop in telegram reply keyboard

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I want to use for loop in telegram reply keyboard.
this is my code:

```
var keyboard = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   keyboard.push([{'text': 'Device'+i}]);
}

var payload = {
    
   'method': 'sendMessage',
   'chat_id': String(chatId),
   'text': text,
   'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
      inline_keyboard: keyboard
   })
}
      
var data = {
     "method": "post",
     "payload": payload,          
}
      
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
```

My code seems true, but don't work, and don't show replay keyboard :(

i also read this post , but don't help to me
[generate inline keyboard telegram bot from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697686/generate-inline-keyboard-telegram-bot-from-the-database)

Comment: what doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What doesn't work? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: don't show replay keyboard

Comment: i wrote code in google app script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed `callback_data`

Try this:

```
keyboard.push([{'text': 'Device'+i, 'callback_data': 'data'}]);
```

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]